# Two monitors, one in portrait mode (vertical), intel UHD 630, screen artifacts / tears

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

### Problem description

I have two monitors with Ubuntu 20.04:

- Primary DELL 24" in landscape mode connected as DP-1
- Secondary BENQ 24" in portrait mode connected as HDMI-1, however it is in fact DVI-D - HDMI connection. Also for some reason Ubuntu display manager in GUI views it like BENQ 22" which is wrong.

So I have screen tearing problem, especially in the browsers while scrolling. On the vertical monitor I have vertical tearing while scrolling and on landscape monitor I have somewhat diagonal tearing while scrolling.

### What I've tried to do:

I've tried to create `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` directory and put this in `20-intel.conf`:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "TearFree"    "true"
   Option      "DRI"    "3"
EndSection
```

After reboot I had my vertical monitor turn back to horizontal and Chrome and Firefox did not render their pages properly. Every click inside their windows seemingly lead to nothing, but if maximized/minimized the rendering was correct. After I tried to make it vertical back in Ubuntu display manager GUI, xorg (? I'm not sure, I'm a noob) crashed.

If I do this without `"DRI" "3"` option then after reboot both monitors have some ugly artifacts.

Comment: Try in Wayland instead.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, can you please be more specific? I've just discovered what Wayland is and I see that in my `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` there is a line `#WaylandEnable=false` which should basically mean that it is enabled, right? What should I do now?

Comment: It means the exact opposite actually. It means Xorg. Reboot or logoff then choose Wayland, can't be more specific than that. The picture here shows the option: https://fossbytes.com/why-components-of-login-screen-in-ubuntu-20-04-looks-so-misaligned/

Comment: @ChanganAuto, thank you very much! Did not do anything except logging off and logging in with Wayland and the problem seems gone.

Comment: That's why Wayland is the default in 21.04 and from now on.

Comment: I have the same issue with Ubuntu Mate 20.04. Surprisingly, after adding `20-intel.conf` the tearing was gone, but so was the audio output. I'm looking for alternatives.